# Should "append to" be "append too"?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

> append parts c to parts b

or

> append parts c too parts b

I know too is used when there are supposed to be amounts, but appending something to something else is adding something to / too it.

Can someone please explain this to me.

Comment: In legal terminology, the word "append" is often used without the "to" as an alternative to the word "attach."  I'm not sure why.  For example, "If a foreign entity operates an interactive website that conducts business in a forum state, then jurisdiction by the forum state would likely append."

Comment: 'too' means 'also'. A general test is that if you can use 'also' then you can use 'too'.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @rhetorician. Attach and append mean different things, although their connotation is similar. **To attach** means to lay hold of, or to seize. The implication is that when you lay hold of something, the two are not separate (so long as it is held). **To append** means to hang or suspend something upon something else. The implication is that the weight is borne by something else. By further extension, we gain the (very old) legal term **to append**, which means roughly *to make a thing possessed*. I suppose in your example it is possessed in terms of legal responsibility.

Comment: @BenMullikin:  Thanks for the additional information.  The study of law--in which I am now engaged--is full of words with nuances of meaning, and consequently they are hard to "pin down" at times.  When you throw in the Latin terms on top of them, well, troubles append!

Answer (score 2):

The word **too** is incorrect. **Too** means *also*. The word to use is the preposition **to**. Word-choice error.

The word **parts** is incorrect. Each part is a single part; therefore, the correct form of the word is **part**. Grammatical error.

The phrase has to be:

> "*append **part** c **to part** b*".

Comment: Why can't you append multiple parts? "*Append these lines to those files*" seems like a perfectly grammatical construction.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Yes, of course you can append multiple parts, but "append parts c to parts b" doesn't make sense **to me**, & it's typical of the kind of singular/plural error that EFL students often make when writing and speaking English, especially if their native language doesn't generally use plural endings but relies on context or other clues to indicate plurality, eg, Chinese & Japanese. If the phrase the OP had asked about were something like "append the indicated c parts to the highlighted b parts", I wouldn't have said anything about a grammatical problem. But there's no such context.

Answer (score 0):

Only "*append parts c **to** parts b*" is correct. *To* is a preposition which indicates to what you are appending. *Too* is an adverb indicating that you are appending *c* in addition to something else, and can generally be substituted with "*also*"—as in "*append parts c also parts b*," which clearly makes no sense.

I think the following example will illustrate the point:

> Append parts c to parts b, then append parts d, too.